How do you add a header in Flutter? I use GettX right noow
Sorry I am still new to Flutter.
How do you add a header in Flutter for every tabs for globally?
I assume it'a one place.
I use GettX right now.
Unfortunately I con'f find it in Google.

Which header you mean ? api request header or page header ? or Do you have example design you want ?

Sorry, page header that has NO API calls Only visual stuff/

Can you show design or something similar to design you want ?

I don't have my design yet :(
